# importing module and associated definitions/functions/objects into python namespace using import *

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, import, python-import

There is something that I don't understand about importing the modules in python. My understanding was that if we use from ipython command prompt  e.g. `In [1]: from module import *` 
then it would import all the submodules and function definitions associated with specific `<module>`.

For example,  I need to import `ndimage` package from `scipy`. But
`from scipy import *` does not import everything associated with `scipy`. 
Only way it seems to work is to use: `from scipy import ndimage` or `import scipy.ndimage`.

A general, is there a way to know the list of default functions/modules/definitions that are imported (or not imported) using `import *` command?

PS: I am using Anaconda distribution of python (2.7) on Windows 7 OS.

Comment: Related: [What exactly does "import \*" import?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2360724)

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the documentation.  In the case of `scipy` [this intro page on importing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/api.html) is important.

With a package, the `__all__` variable in the `__init__` file determines what is loaded with a `import *`.

A `*` import is discouraged; a convenient alias is better, e.g. `import numpy as np`.  That way it is clear when you are using code from a module.

Answer (score 0):

`ndimage` is a submodule under `scipy`. This submodule is not imported by scipy's `__init__.py` so it will not get imported with `import scipy`.

You can see what is actually imported with `import scipy` by reading scipy's `__init__.py`. In my system it is available at:

`>>> scipy.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/__init__.pyc'`

Scipy imports fairly little of its own names, but a lot from numpy. I see a `from numpy import *` there so you got access to many numpy names, e.g., `scipy.array` and `scipy.mean`.